# Multi-colored polyominoes inside a 7x7 grid

Tags: mathematics, optimization, polyomino, packing

Can you place four red [trominoes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tromino), four green [tetrominoes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetromino) and four blue [pentominoes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentomino) inside an 7x7 grid, such that:

- No two polyominoes overlap
- No two polyominoes of the same color touch each other orthogonally (horizontally or vertically)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think this would work as a possibility

> [image]

Comment: oooh very nice and pretty! Amazingly that only took you 7 minutes.

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky I suppose that once you decide to solve it rot13(hfvat flzzrgel, naq ynl qbja ornzf sebz gur prager fdhner gb gur rqtrf, gura gur erfg orpbzrf snveyl rnfl fvapr gur erznvavat pbearef pna or svyyrq va nyzbfg serryl). You could make it harder by adding the condition that red and green cannot touch, and I think that has only one solution.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis please post that solution

Answer (score 11):

Here is a solution in which the red and green do not touch.

> [image]

Answer (score 4):

An obvious upper bound for the maximum number of distinct shapes is $2+4+4=10$, and...

> ...this solution attains that upper bound:
>  [image]

Comment: What do you mean by 2+4+4?

Comment: Ah, you mean the shapes, ok I got it now.